# SQL: Extract most recent timestamp from a dictionary text column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, select, jsonb

Given a table with a single column, where each row is a string representation of a dict of timestamps produced by a Python program, is there a way using only SQL to produce only the most recent timestamp and its associated value?

#### Example Row:

```py
{"2018-08-12T00:00:00": 88888.8, "2018-08-12T15:00:00": 88888.8, "2018-08-12T03:00:00": 88888.8, "2018-08-12T12:00:00": 88888.8, "2018-08-12T21:00:00": 88888.8, "2018-08-12T18:00:00": 88888.8, "2018-08-12T06:00:00": 88888.8, "2018-08-12T09:00:00": 88888.8}
```

#### Expected output if CSV:

```
timestamp,value
"2018-08-12T21:00:00",88888.8
```

Comment: What is the datatype of that column?

Comment: @GMB The column containing a string representation of a dict is of type: varchar

Answer (score 0):

As far as shown in your sample data, the dict values are valid json strings. I would suggest converting them to jsonb object; you can then use `jsonb_object_keys()` to extract the keys, sort them, and retrieve the value that correspond to the greatest key:

```
select z.ts, (t.dict::jsonb) ->> z.ts val
from t
cross join lateral (
    select ts
    from jsonb_object_keys(t.dict::jsonb) x(ts)
    order by ts desc
    limit 1
) z
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2763026321b07e7a0c0468891e2db81a)**:

```
with t as (select '{"2018-08-12T00:00:00": 88888.8, "2018-08-12T15:00:00": 88888.8, "2018-08-12T03:00:00": 88888.8, "2018-08-12T12:00:00": 88888.8, "2018-08-12T21:00:00": 88888.8, "2018-08-12T18:00:00": 88888.8, "2018-08-12T06:00:00": 88888.8, "2018-08-12T09:00:00": 88888.8}' dict)
select z.ts, (t.dict::jsonb) ->> z.ts val
from t
cross join lateral (
    select ts
    from jsonb_object_keys(t.dict::jsonb) x(ts)
    order by ts desc
    limit 1
) z
```

```
ts                  | val    
:------------------ | :------
2018-08-12T21:00:00 | 88888.8
```